# When the UseDefaultCredentials property of an HttpClientHandler is set to true, how do credentials actually get resolved for a request?

Tags: .net, authentication, http, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

When creating an instance of an [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0), you can pass an instance of an [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-7.0) to configure how you want the client to behave. One of these options is the [UseDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials?view=net-7.0) property, it's purpose being to control "whether default credentials are sent with requests by the handler". In my personal experience, this purpose often boils down to enabling requests to a service that requires NTLM authentication, just set it to 'true' and it's handled for you.

What I want to understand is **how** the underlying HTTP handler is able to provide my credentials (i.e. as the logged-in user) without me having to explicitly provide them via a username/password pair. When I look at non-.NET libraries that add support for NTLM authentication (e.g. [axios-ntlm](https://github.com/Catbuttes/axios-ntlm) for Node.js, [python-ntlm](https://github.com/mullender/python-ntlm) for Python), I see that they support the protocol itself but stop short of doing anything to get the credentials of the current user. Ultimately what I want is the magic "just works" experience of NTLM authentication for a client application but without using .NET.

After looking at libraries like I mentioned above, as well as digging through the [.NET runtime source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) (I mean it **has** to be in there somewhere right?), I have so far been unable to understand how this magic is accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I figured out the basics of how it works. It's essentially a combination of the Win32 SSPI functions AcquireCredentialsHandle and InitializeSecurityContext, the former can provide a handle to the currently logged-in user's credentials and the latter provides the token used during NTLM authentication based on those credentials.

I haven't put my understanding to the test, but this more or less solves the mystery for me.